# c++: a program to find the average of very high numbers?

Tags: c++, average

so im trying to make a c++ program that can find the average of very high numbers (the range was <10^19)

heres my attemp:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

    long double a,b,result;
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cin>>b;
    result=(a+b)/2;
    std::cout<<result<<"\n";
}
```

but somehow i did not the result i expected. my teacher said there was a "trick" and there was no need to even use double. but i search and researched and did not found the trick. so any help?

Comment: Firstly, what is the result and what is the expected result? Then, why do those two differ and what needs to be done differently in order to achieve the correct result? Also, what was the input that caused the problem? Consider mocking the input using a stringstream, too!

Comment: 64 bit int... almost works... doubles would give an approximation only...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the result i get is in exponential numbers. if i enter 
10^19 and 10^19  (in normal numbers of course) i get 1e+019
but i want my result to be not in exponential numbers (10000000000000000000).

Comment: If your teacher said that there is a "trick", I assume it must have to do with the two numbers. It would help it you described the subject you are currently going through in your class and also to give the full wording of your task.

Comment: You could consider a [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) library like [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/)

Comment: @BasvanStein: a = 1, b = 1, result = 0 => there is an issue with this formula :)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Overkill, especially for an assignment. The values given fit into a 64 bits integer (though their sum may not).

Comment: @BasvanStein: Check my answer, unfortunately numbers up to 10^19 require 19 digits and even `long double` only guarantees 18 digits of precision. Going the floating point route therefore is not an option. Your idea is not wrong though, with just a slight adjustment you could make it work: just handle the case of odd integers :)

Comment: True, I see. I think I myself would take the bigNumber library approach or store each number in two variables (first 9 digits in the first and last 10 in the second for example)

Comment: `(a+b)/2` == `(a/2) + (b/2)`, maybe you could investigate that avenue.

Answer (score 2):

When using floating point numbers you have to consider their *precision*, it is represented by `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` in base 10, and the following program can give them (they may depend on your platform):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    std::cout << "float: " << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10 << "\n";
    std::cout << "double: " << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 << "\n";
    std::cout << "long double: " << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

On [ideone](http://ideone.com/Ni3WxI) I get:

```
float: 6
double: 15
long double: 18
```

Which is consistent with 32 bits, 64 bits and 80 bits floating point numbers (respectively).

Since 10<sup>19</sup> is above 18 digits (it has 20), the type you have chosen lacks the necessary precision to represent all numbers below it, and no amount of computation can recover the lost data.

---

Let's switch back to integrals, while their range is more limited, they have a higher degree of precision for the same amount of bits. A 64 bits signed integer has a maximum of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 and the unsigned version goes up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615. For comparison 10<sup>19</sup> is 10,000,000,000,000,000,000.

A `uint64_t` (from `<cstdint>`) gives you to necessary building block, however you'll be teetering on the edge of overflow: 2 times 10<sup>19</sup> is too much.

You now have to find a way to compute the average without adding the two number together.

> Supposing two integers M, N such that M <= N, (M + N) / 2 = M + (N - M) / 2

Comment: `uint64_t` is C++11-only, and at that point, you might as well use `unsigned long long`. It's theoretically possible for it to be more than 64 bits, doesn't require a header, and is guaranteed to exist (though the likelihood of `uint64_t` not existing seems pretty low).

Comment: @chris: I see little reason, in 2015, to not suppose the availability of C++11 unless explicitly specified (like... I don't use it at work yet :(). In any case, I much prefer recommending types with *explicit* bit width rather than meander in the miasma of C integral types where the range of values covered are up to the whims of the platform.

Comment: Right, I was much less focused on the needing C++11 part and more focused on the "now that you have C++11, there's an alternative" part. Thanks for sharing your opinion on which alternative to use.